# What is the difference betweeen (trigger) and (click) in Angular Dart Components?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I have found that some people are using `(trigger)` for binding click events on eg. `<material-button>` elements, while I was always using `(click)`. What is the difference between those 2 directives?

```
<material-button (click)="doStuff()">

<material-button (trigger)="doStuff()">
```

to me those does exactly the same thing, but I can be wrong.

Comment: Can you please share some ref links to the second syntax? That doesn't look right.

Comment: Sure, https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_button - Outputs section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [Official document](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_button)

**trigger** is the name of an `@Output()` param that emits an event whenever the button is activated via click, tap, or key press.

`(click)` works only for click event, but since `(trigger)` is a custom event emitter, it will work for click, tap, and key press as well.

Comment: Onclick will not do the same ?

Comment: That is something that crossed my mind, but had to ask here. Please add this to your answer and ill accept.

Answer (score 2):

The most practical difference between `(trigger)` and `(click)` on `<material-button>`, is that `(trigger)` events get filtered by the `[disabled]` attribute while `(click)` does not.

`<material-button (trigger)="someFunction()" [disabled]="true">` will not call `someFunction()` onClick.

`<material-button (click)="someFunction()" [disabled]="true">` will call `someFunction()` onClick.

Generally, I would suggest binding to the `(trigger)` directive when using `<material-button>`, less code to change if you later decide to add a `[disabled]` condition.